# How to initiliaze data with props value without call the props in template?

Tags: vue.js

I have `props` structured like this.

```
props: {
  propsChooseColor: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}
```

The `props` received as expected(checked with vue devtools).
[image: props working]

And then I try to initialize `data` with the props value like the [official suggestion](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

```
chooseColor: this.propsChooseColor
```

The problem is :

- If I call `chooseColor` and `propsChooseColor` in `template`, the
  `chooseColor` have same value as the props.
  But if I don't call `propsChooseColor`, the `chooseColor` value is `""`.

E.g Value of `chooseColor` will empty.

```
<template>
  ...
  data color: {{ chooseColor }} // RETURN ""
  ...
</template>
```

E.g Value of `chooseColor` will same as `propsChooseColor`.

```
<template>
  ...
  data color: {{ chooseColor }} // RETURN BLACK
  props color: {{ propsChooseColor }} // RETURN BLACK
  ...
</template>
```

I try to debug it and found that `beforeUpdate hook` is called if the `props` called in template.
[image: debugging problem]

What is happening? How do I initialize data without call the props? Approach usinh Computed property might not suited because i need to modify the data.

Edit. I also fetching data in the root component **beforeRouteEnter** hook like this.

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  const _id = to.query._id
  const size = to.query.size
  const color = to.query.color

  axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/api/product-details/${_id}`)
    .then(response => {
      next(vm => {
        vm.id = _id
        vm.chooseSize = size
        vm.chooseColor = color
        vm.product = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data))

        axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/api/product/all-seller/${vm.product.product_fullName}`)
          .then(response => {
            vm.productAllSeller = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data))
            vm.fetchdataComplete = true
        })
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Seems to work well on this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/y2x81pw9zj Are you sure something else doesn't break it?

Comment: Maybe it come from the root component where i fetch the data in the **beforeRouteEnter** hook  because if i put simple string in the root component like your example it become work as expected but I'm not sure. I put the fetching code in the updated question.